# How can I change the language parameter of an exe file generated by launch4j?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, exe, launch4j

I'm producing a windows executable EXE file of my java program with an ANT task of launch4j in Eclipse.
In the ANT task I'm using a saved launch4j config file (xml) and additionally overwrite the version information.

```
<launch4j
    configFile="${launch4j.config.dir}/paginaEPUBChecker.xml"
    fileVersion="${program.version.number}"
    txtFileVersion="${program.version.txtNumber}"
    productVersion="${program.version.number}"
    txtProductVersion="${program.version.txtNumber}"
/>
```

Everything is working perfect so far. The executable is built and runs just fine.

But when looking into the file's property details (right click => properties => details) I get the "language" property with the value "English (US)" even though I'm working with a German Windows version and therefore would expect it to be "German".

Do you know whether there is a (probably hidden or undocumented?) launch4j config option to set the language property to "German"?

Comment: Launch4J provides Java source codes. The Windows resource building part in the path `src\net\sf\launch4j\RCBuilder.java` which Launch4J later uses it with Windres utility to create the executable, the default resource "LANGUAGE" is LANG_NEUTRAL with SUBLANG_DEFAULT, causing it to fall back to English (US). You can verify this using the open-source ResEdit utility upon the created executable. That is why it is not in German (LANG_GERMAN with SUBLANG_NEUTRAL) see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and http://wiki.winehq.org/SublangNeutral

Comment: With that explanation, you may need to ask for a feature request from Launch4J developers to provide a way to generate language specific resource when building an executable.

Comment: Thank you for the information :) That seems reasonable.I'll probably write a feature request about that...

Comment: Better late than never: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3598734&group_id=95944&atid=613103

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was indeed a missing feature in launch4j back then.

Version 3.9 (2016-07-20) added this feature and it works fine.

See [CHANGELOG](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/changelog.html) and [issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/feature-requests/69/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool called Resource Hacker to change the properties of an exe file.